# ReactJS: How to expand and show API calling in Tree View Node Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, treeview, jsx

I have tree View Material UI in React. Can it be possible that the API called after the node is clicked and append the child to the node clicked so that it won't update to the other children in node using state?

The logic which I'm using is that in Tree View I'm calling the API. And after response it throws me arrays which I have to use map to show. But when I click on first node and after that when the other node is clicked the child of previous one is appending to the second node.

```
<TreeView
  className={classes.root1}
  defaultExpandIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon />}
  defaultCollapseIcon={<ArrowDropUpIcon />}
  defaultEndIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon />}
  disableSelection={true}
  expanded={expanded}
  onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
>
  {renderTree(row, index)}
</TreeView>;
```

The render tree function:

```
const renderTree = (row, index) => {
  return (
    <StyledTreeItem
      style={{ padding: "3px", marginLeft: 18 }}
      onIconClick={() => {
        handleIconListItemOrgClick(row, index, index);
      }}
      onLabelClick={(event) =>
        handleLabelListOUItemClick(row, index, index, event)
      }
      key={row.organizationalUnitId}
      labelText={row.organizationalUnitName}
      labelIcon={AccountTree}
    >
      {Array.isArray(treeViewChildren.domainGroupList)
        ? treeViewChildren.domainGroupList.map((node, i) => {
            return (
              <StyledTreeItem
                id="exdendedG"
                style={{ padding: "3px", marginLeft: 18 }}
                onClick={(e) => handleTreeSubItems(e, node, i)}
                key={i}
                nodeId={node.groupId}
                labelText={node.groupName}
                labelIcon={GroupExpIcon}
              >
                {/* {renderTree(node)} */}
              </StyledTreeItem>
            );
          })
        : null}
    </StyledTreeItem>
  );
};
```

And the function for API calling is:

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState('');
const [treeViewChildren, setTreeViewChildren] = useState({});
const handleIconListItemOrgClick = (row, index, nodeId) => {
  setExpanded([`${nodeId}`]);
  console.log(row.organizationalUnitDistinguishName);

  var expanded = JSON.stringify({
    option: "GetSubObjectList",
    distinguishedUserName: row.organizationalUnitDistinguishName,
  });
  const result = ApiService(expanded);
  //---------->Groups Lists<--------------
  result.then((response) => {
    const item = response;
    item.domainGroupList.forEach(function (gr) {
      gr.groupImportedAs = "Normal";
    });
    setTreeViewChildren(item);

    console.log("Server response", item);
  });
};
```

How to append the child on the node using index ?. And when the other node is clicked it shouldn't append the child of other nodes ?

Comment: try adding ```https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation```  on you click handler

Comment: I have tried but its not working. It will be in a working mode once the react code is modified.